# How to add arguments to the Cloud SQL proxy with AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine

With the following app.yml config file:

```
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME
```

all debug messages generated by the [cloud_sql_proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) command are logged in [stderr by default](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/pull/150) which flood the log system with a lot of meaningless messages.

When I'm running the cloud_sql_proxy command line locally it's possible to hide all these messages with `--verbose=false` option.

How I can do the same with the app.yml config file, so all debug messages are ignored on AppEngine containers ?

Comment: I have not found a good way to do this as there is almost no documentation on this, but I was reading that you could exclude this logs from your stackdriver when you create logs exclusions. This is well documented here at https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions, although it does not stop the application from silence the connection.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the tip, that's a perfect workaround!